# How to know if a customer has already connected her account through stripe connect to my website?

Tags: django, stripe-payments

This is my view in Django:

```
    @login_required 
    def merchant(request):
       t = {}   

       merchant_data, created = MerchantData.objects.get_or_create(user=request.user)

       if not created:
          stripe.api_key = merchant_data.access_token
          account = stripe.Account.retrieve()

          t.update({ 'account': account }) 

       return render_to_response('pages_dynamic/merchant.html', t, context_instance=RequestContext(request))
```

I am able to retrieve successfully the customer's account. Merchant.html has the "connect with Stripe" button. My problem is that I only want to show the button if the user/customer has not connected her account already. How do I figure that out? Is there anything in the customer account I can check out in my html template, or do I have to look somewhere else?

Answer (score 0):

It's a bit hard to know what you mean. The only way a customer can "connect" their account to your website is by you sending them to the payment gateway, and then storing the token returned from there in your database. Since you need to store the token, you should know if the customer has registered.

Comment: Connect in the sense they've authorized you to make payments/charge customers on their behalf using Stripe Connect https://stripe.com/docs/connect/getting-started

Comment: Yes, that's my point. Surely you either have something in `merchant_data.access_token` - in which case they've connected - or you don't, when they haven't.

Comment: Thanks Daniel, but that's not the way it works. The access token can be invalid or revoked. I have to query stripe in order to check out that it is still valid.

Answer (score 0):

Just in case somebody has the same issue. What works for me is to use the customer's access_token to request the customer's account. If for some reason the customer is disconnected (e.g. the customer has revoked my app access to her stripe account), the operation fails.